# How to create a nested array store that updates to local storage in Svelte?

Tags: arrays, local-storage, svelte, svelte-store

I want to create an object as a store, where arrays in the object can be used as stores as well. Each array needs to be updated (subscribed to), and the object needs to be updated to local storage as well.

Here's the structure of the object

```js
{
   "expenses":[
      {
         "name":"sam",
         "id":1
      },
      {
         "name":"bob",
         "id":2
      }
   ],
   "options":[
      ...
   ]
}
```

Here's the code I have so far:

```js
import { writable } from "svelte/store";

// get local storage
let storage = localStorage.getItem("userInputs");

// if storage exists, use it. otherwise set empty array
export let userInputs = writable(JSON.parse(storage) || []);
export let userExpenses = writable(storage.expenses || []);
export let userOptions = writable(storage.options || []);

// subscribe inputs to localStorage
userInputs.subscribe((val) =>
    localStorage.setItem("userInputs", JSON.stringify(val))
);
```

I want to be able to use **userExpenses** and **userOptions** as stores throughout my app. When these arrays are updated, they need to update in the master **userInputs** object, which would need to be pushed to localStorage.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use svelte's awesome [derived](https://svelte.dev/docs#derived) function for that, e.g.

```
// create userInputs as derived which results in a store
// that is updated whenever userExpenses or userOptions
// are.
const userInputs = derived(
   [userExpenses, userOptions], 
   ([ue, uo]) => ({
      userExpenses: ue,
      userOptions: uo
   })
);

// sync to localStorage
userInputs.subscribe(val => {
    localStorage.setItem("userInputs", JSON.stringify(val));
});
```

Comment: Amazing - this is what I was looking for. I came across derived in my search but it went over my head.

Comment: Glad it helped. It also went over my head when I first encountered `derived`. But once you have used it a couple of times you won't want to miss it.